# reliable paid time server for global time using javascript

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

I'm looking for reliable paid time server for global time using Javascript. I need to synchronize my distributed server with local time, which will be consumed from the time service (in case the client PC is not NTP synchronized).

Thanks.

Comment: Here, I googled it for you http://www.worldtimeserver.com/time_zone_guide/

Comment: I don't think it provides reliable and accurate time and also if the server is far away from the client then it will add network latency.

Comment: What are the criterion for "accurate" and "reliable"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one

- http://json-time.appspot.com

And deploy it to Google App Engine yourself to have full control over it.

- https://github.com/simonw/json-time

The reliability will then be of Google's App Engine.